# Setting an Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I tried to find a method to change a size of array of Objects, but actually I couldn't find an answer.

I got 2 classes, `Main` and `Element`.

`Element` looks like this:

```
public class Element {
    
        int posX,posY;
        int elementNumber;
        
        Element(int posX,int posY,int elementNumber){
            this.posX=posX;
            this.posY=posY;
            this.elementNumber=elementNumber;
        }
        
}
```

and the `Main` class look like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Element[] arrayOfElements = new Element[2];

        //----- CREATING ELEMENT 0 AND ELEMENT 1
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            System.out.println("Setting "+i+" element");
            arrayOfElements[i]=new Element(i+20,i+40,i);
            System.out.println("posX for "+arrayOfElements[i].elementNumber+" is: "+arrayOfElements[i].posX);
            System.out.println("posY for "+arrayOfElements[i].elementNumber+" is: "+arrayOfElements[i].posY);
        }

        //----- TRYING TO CREATE ELEMENT 2, GETTING ERROR HERE
        arrayOfElements[2]=new Element(22,42,2);
        System.out.println("posX for "+arrayOfElements[2].elementNumber+" is: "+arrayOfElements[2].posX);
        System.out.println("posY for "+arrayOfElements[2].elementNumber+" is: "+arrayOfElements[2].posY);   
        
        
        System.out.println("Program ends here.");
    }
    
}
```

I am setting the Element size to [2], but I would like to change it in the program after some operations, because it is up to user input, how many elements the `Element` object will have.

If I try to add next `arrayOfElements` after the loop (for, its triggered an error.)

How can I pass it?

Comment: You should use a List<Element> instead of an array If you need to add elements.

Comment: You couldn't find a way because there isn't a way ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of an array in Java. Once an array has been created, its size is fixed.

If you need to change the size, then the only thing you can do is create a new array of the right size, and copy the elements of the old array into the new array, and then use the new array from that point on.

For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

// ...

Element[] arrayOfElements = new Element[2];

// ...

// Create a new array of length 3, copy the old array into the new one,
// and assign the new array to the variable arrayOfElements.
arrayOfElements = Arrays.copyOf(arrayOfElements, 3);

// Assign a new Element to the new element at index 2.
arrayOfElements[2] = new Element(...);
```

Alternatively, you can use a collection class such as an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

```
List<Element> listOfElements = new ArrayList<>();

// You can easily add elements to a List
listOfElements.add(new Element(...));
listOfElements.add(new Element(...));
listOfElements.add(new Element(...));
```